"spawn nix-instantiate ENOENT" Error in VSCode
I'm setting up my flakes in nixos and wanted to use VSCode to edit my configuration.nix file. Now, I'm using "user" in place of my username on nixos for this code snippet so I don't reveal my real name, but I ran this code to give permission to VSCode:
sudo chown -R "user": /etc/nixos/configuration.nix

But after I did this, I got this error in VSCode:
spawn nix-instantiate ENOENT


I had to rectify the downvote first, because I am having the same problem using VSCode from WSL. Even adding the path to the config doesn't work. My VSCode always tries to run nix-instantiate on the Windows side. But giving anonymous downvotes is typical StackOverflow I guess.
